# Create a view where if row exists in one table, put set value, and if it exists in multiple tables, put 'multiple'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I'm trying to build a SQL View, based on a main table and four activity tables. There are four activity types, Activity1, Activity2, etc.

The tables are linked by the main table's primary key. The activity tables have it linked as a foreign key. A primary key might have multiple activity records in the same table, or multiple records across many of the activity tables.

I want to create a view that has a column for every primary key, and if it has any amount of records in only one activity table, then the column will contain the name of that activity("Activity1", "Activity2", etc.) and if it exists in more than one activity table to put "Multiple" instead, and if it exists in none of those tables to put "None".

I've been trying to use EXISTS in SQL but I'm not sure how to use a default value such as "Multiple" and "None" in place if more than one row exists.

This isn't a problem in C#, but I need it done in a SQL View specifically and I'm at a loss.

Comment: show a proper data sample and expected result

Answer (score 0):

i think you just need a case statement in your view like :

```
select 

case when iif(a1.activity is null , 0,1) + iif(a2.activity is null , 0,1) +iif(a3.activity is null , 0,1)+iif(a4.activity is null , 0,1) > 1 then "Multiple" 
when iif(a1.activity is null , 0,1) + iif(a2.activity is null , 0,1) +iif(a3.activity is null , 0,1)+iif(a4.activity is null , 0,1) = 0 then "none"
else COALESCE ( a1.activity,a2.activity,a3.activity,a4.activity) end as [activity]

from main_table m
left join activity1_table a1
on m.key = a1.key
left join activity2_table a2
on m.key = a2.key
left join activity3_table a3
on m.key = a3.key
left join activity4_table a4
on m.key = a4.key
```

Comment: That looks like what I need. I'll test it out and let you know.